# Insert value using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an  tag, and need to assign value to it's attribute within my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">     
  <xsl:template match="/">
```

I need to assign value to the trId attribute, but the way I have it now don't work,
what is the right way to do it?

```
<ABX trId="<xsl:value-of select="CODE_VALUE"/>">


  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<ABX>
    <xsl:attribute name="trId"><xsl:value-of select="CODE_VALUE"/></xsl:attribute>
</ABX>
```

The XSLT `<attribute`> tag will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could simply do this:

```
<ABX trId="{CODE_VALUE}"/>
```

The expression inside curly braces is evaluated and the result is put into the attribute value. See [Section 7.6.2, Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in the spec.